# Resizing content in uinavigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In some cases I need to add a search bar or tab bar to my application. I use UIViewController for the UINavigationController content. Changing the frame on the UIViewControllers wont do anything.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Here's code which fails in the initWithStyle method of a UIViewController (Also fails in other methods):

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - 49);
```

That might not be perfect code but it should at least move the view.

Comment: which cases? what are you trying to do? what do you expect to get? you must provide good questions if you want good answers.

Comment: On a UINavigationController you display views, right? Well how do you resize these views inside the UINavigationController? I need to do this because I need to display bars over the top.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code.  Resizing views that are inside a UINavigationController is done no differently to resizing any other view.  Do you mean it's in the navigation controller UI itself (i.e. in the title bar), or in one of the ViewControllers in the navigation controller's stack?

Comment: Yes, in the stack. I've changed the frame and it does nothing. I'll post some code then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a technique I use to make room beneath a UINavigationController for an AdBannerView that is global to the app.  Perhaps you can do something similar.

[global ADBannerView in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669272/global-adbannerview-in-iphone-app)

Comment: Okay, so basically taking the content view and replacing it with another view to put the original view into.

Comment: I'll give it a go when I get around to it (Maybe tomorrow). Thanks for the suggestion.