# iAd shown below UITabBarController, on screen all the time?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I'd like to add an iAd bannerView below a UITabBarController. Preferably, the actual Tab Bar would stay the same size, moving up and down with the banner view, and the views for each tab would be resized.

Is this possible or even allowed? If so, how would I go about doing this? Any tutorial links are appreciated.

If I had this setup, would I have resizing issues with the UINavigationControllers and their subviews?

Comment: I don't think you can resize a UITabBarController's TabBar. But you can resize a UITabBar of your own. But (again) you probably gonna have some problems with icon size etc. You shouldn't have problems with UINavigationControllers' subviews, just configure them as if you hadn't UITabbar (Bottom Bar = Unspecified) so the views won't do anything to take that into account.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking more of the nav controller resizing and the tab bar just moving  up and down. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the technique I use, albeit for UINavigationController not UITabBarController.  But I'm fairly certain you could make it work for a root UITabBarController.

[global ADBannerView in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669272/global-adbannerview-in-iphone-app)

While not mentioned in the SO question/answer, I do animate the ad appearing and disappearing, resizing the content view in the process.  I've had no issues with this, and Apple's approved 3 apps with this code.

Comment: That you very much! I'll try this later today and hopefully you've answered my question! Much appreciated.